# Does my segwit node only have segwit blocks?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, segregated-witness, witness-data

My segwit node makes a `gettxout` RPC query and checks the `scriptPubKey.type` is `"witness_v0_keyhash"` and does things accordingly.

To my understanding old nodes have different blocks and if I happened to fetch a block from an old node, what will my node do? Will it simply store it as is and ultimately result in not getting the desired `"witness_v0_keyhash"` response when I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BIP 144 equipped nodes doesn't fetch blocks from old nodes since they are only capable of providing witness stripped blocks.

If someone sent it a stripped block (e.g. by lying about their support or whatnot) and it contained any segwit using transactions then it would get dropped and the peer disconnected-- basically treated like merkle tree malleability.